How to define BatchNorm3d in tensorflow
PyTorch has three types of BatchNorm layers: BatchNorm1d, BatchNorm2d and BatchNorm3d.
TensorFlow has only one BatchNormalization layer.
Are these layers equivalent? I mean, the three PyTorch layers can be defined using that layer from TensorFlow?
Are there any parameters of TensorFlow layer that need to be adjusted to have it achieve the behavior of PyTorch layers?
